# Assets missing after building and running app in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have built the game and I am running it on my phone, in the game window on the editor, the game runs great and has no problems. Whereas the version on my phone is missing the main character, including all the scripts, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you are loading the main character asset.
"LoadAssetAtPath" i.e. only works in the editor, it will not work when the game is compiled.

Comment: After checking the logs, I discovered a Vulkan API error, not sure why, but I have seen a few people have the same problem online, using the same shaders I am using (URP), but their solutions didn't work for me